# Variable refuses to be set to a different value after first declaration

Tags: windows, loops, batch-file

In a for each loop, I'm trying to perform a task on each iteration except the first. This is my attempt

```
@echo off

set sources=file1.txt file2.txt
set output=output.txt
set comment_prefix=--

break>%output%
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set first=1
for %%a in (%sources%) do (
    if %first%==0 (
        echo.>> %output%
        echo.>> %output%
        echo.>> %output%
    )
    set first=0
    echo %first%

    echo %comment_prefix%>>%output% %%a
    echo.>> %output%
    type %%a>>%output%
)
```

The problem is that the variable `first` seems to be constantly set to `1`, even though it should be set to `0` after the first iteration (I think)...

- How can I make the value of `first` change to zero?
- Is there a better way to make a condition to check if the iteration is *not* the first one?

Cheers

**EDIT:**

This is the current output

```
1
1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are setting *and* expanding (reading) the variable within the same line or block of code, so you need [delayed expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html). Otherwise, `%first%` will expand to the value the variable was set to at the time the entire line/block is parsed (so the variable *is* in fact set, but an old value is read). To use delayed expansion, replace `%first%` by `!first!`.

However, since you are using the variable as a boolean flag only, you could reflect the boolean False by an empty variable rather than by the value `0`, so you could use `if not defined first` instead of `if !first!==0`, which delayed expansion is not necessary for:

```dos
set "first=1"
for %%a in (%sources%) do (
    if not defined first (
        echo.>> %output%
        echo.>> %output%
        echo.>> %output%
    )
    set "first="

    echo %comment_prefix%>>%output% %%a
    echo.>> %output%
    type %%a>>%output%
)
```